# xpages javascript code for hiding a button

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have a button on my custom control which I want to make it visible in a computed way, so I tried:

```
currentDocument.isEditable() && getComponent("djTextarea5").value!=""
```

or

```
currentDocument.isEditable() && dojo.byId("djTextarea5").value!=""
```

at the `Visible` property, but I doesn't work. My `DjTextarea5` is not binded on any field from a datasource.

I tried at the `rendered` property:

```
<xp:button value="My Hidden Button" id="button1"
            styleClass="lotusFormButton">

            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:currentDocument.isEditable() && getComponent("djTextarea5").value}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"
                id="eventHandler2">
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Visible property? Do you mean the rendered or loaded property?

Comment: dojo.byId will not work. The dojo library is Client-Side JavaScript, so cannot be use in server-side calculations, like the rendered property.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten Visible, at the button features. There are also the width,height,name,label accelerator and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does work:

```
currentDocument.isEditable() && getComponent("djTextarea1").value
```

You don't have to test `!=""`. If you just test for a value in JavaScript it returns `false` if value is `null` or `""` and otherwise `true`. In your case it is important to test for null too.

`.value` is fine. You don't have to get the value with `.getValue()`.

In case your component "djTextarea1" is connected to document's field you should use the  field instead the component in your code like

```
currentDocument.isEditable() && document1.getValue("fieldname")
```

**Update:**

The best solution in your case is to use CSJS as you want to show button as soon as a value is entered in "djTextarea5". Here is the code you need:

```
<xe:djTextarea
    id="djTextarea5"
    value="#{frmDoc.txt_names}">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onChange"
        submit="false">
        <xe:this.script><![CDATA[
        if (document.getElementById("#{id:djTextarea5}").value) {
            document.getElementById("#{id:button1}").style.display = 'inline';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("#{id:button1}").style.display = 'none';
        }]]></xe:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:djTextarea>
<xp:button
    value="Do something with djTextarea"
    id="button1">
    <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        currentDocument.isEditable() && frmDoc.getValue("txt_names") ?          
            "display:inline" : 
            "display:none"
    }]]></xp:this.style>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: I think frmDoc.getValue("txt_names")  should read currentDocument.getValue("txt_names") and the solution works well :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need currentDocument.isEditable() && getComponent("djTextarea5").getValue()!="" - you can't just reference the property itself, you need to call the relevant getter, which will usually be "get" + the property name, capitalising the first letter of the property.

In the SSJS, on the left-hand side, there's a tab for Reference. One of the options on the drop-down there for Control Declaration Snippets. There you can select any control on the page. It will cast the variable to the relevant Java class, providing typeahead of all methods like getValue()

Comment: thanks. I tried your suggestion, but my button now is always visible, even if the textarea is empty